# In Terraria, what range do the different tiers of tools have?

Tags: terraria

I just started a new character, and I noticed that the Copper Pickaxe seems to have a shorter range than the Molten Pickaxe. Never really noticed that when going *up* in pickaxe tiers.

So, what range does each pickaxe have? Do the hammers, axes, and hammer-axes have a specific reach too?

Comment: I -know- it changes by gold, but it might be silver.. You pretty much get one extra block of range. Not going to post as an answer as I am too lazy to track down to which specific item the change happens, its well before molten though ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You begin with a Copper Pickaxe. When standing still, it has a range of 4 feet (2 blocks) above/below the player, and when hugging a wall, the range is 8 feet (4 blocks) in the front. However, starting from Iron Pickaxe, the range gets improved (6 feet/3 blocks above and below, 10 feet/5 blocks up front).

From the [Terraria wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Pickaxe)

I can't find anything on the range of hammers/axes.  The official wiki is down right now.